# How to add another Symfony connection cookie for another domain?

Tags: symfony, security, cookies, dns, fosuserbundle

In a SF 2.8 application with FOS User, I need to setup **a second cookie** for persist authentication, **with another domai**n. My needs are a bit exotic in here :

- App is served over SSL, in HSTS mode (https://a.com)
- App needs to have several iframes in some pages, mot of target sites are NOT ssl (bad, I know, no choice here.).
- Neither removing HSTS nor SSL are options, so the idea is to setup another domain (http://b.com) pointing to the same app but only for the kind of page serving iframes.

It's working so far, except on the authentication part. As we change domains (a to b) and considering that both pages are served on a logged part of the application, I got authentication cookie only for the "a" domain, not for "b" one.

So, I'm looking for a way **to add "b" domain cookie at the same time the regular domain one is added**.

I found

- vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.php that seems to define the cookie
- Tried to substitue class parameter name defined by FOS in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security_rememberme.xml (security.authentication.rememberme.services.persistent.class) but the new service class is never used.

I don't really know if I follow the good path here, feel free to feedback if you have suggestion...

Thanks,

Nicolas